# Do adjectives take strong declension when you have a person's name in genitive before it?

Tags: genitive, adjective-ending, possessive

Basically, which of these is correct?

> Jeffs graues Messer
>
> Jeffs graue Messer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are talking about one knife, the first phrase

> Jeffs graues Messer *(one knife)*

is correct. The second phrase cannot be interpreted as a singular. However, it is the correct plural form:

> Jeffs graue Messer *(multiple knives)*.

In the title you are referring to the strong declension and whether it is used after *Jeffs*. The answer is **yes**. *Jeffs* does not act as an article but could be replaced by another genitive construction:

> des Mannes graues Messer

---

Please be aware that the genitive can be moved to the back; then an article is needed. In summary, the following forms are acceptable German:

> (1) Jeffs graues Messer
>   (2) des Mannes graues Messer
>   (3) das graue Messer Jeffs
>   (4) das graue Messer des Mannes

Phrases (1) and (4) are perfect German; (2) sounds old-fashioned; (3) uses a somewhat atypical positioning.

Comment: If you are learning to speak German, however, restrict yourself to using (1) and, in writing, (4), because (2) and (3) are usually replaced by _von_ + Dat constructs nowadays: _das graue Messer von Jeff / dem Mann_, so you basically only need to know them to understand older texts.